# Different color for table of contents entry and page numbers

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab

I am generating a clickable (=with links) table of contents. In order to emphasize the 'clickability' of the entries I want them colored as links (i.e. blue color and underline).

I have this code for setting the style:

```
toc = TableOfContents()
toc.levelStyles[0].fontName = 'Arial Bold'
toc.levelStyles[0].fontSize = 12
toc.levelStyles[0].textColor = '#0000cc'
```

and use this code to add each entry:

```
toc.addEntry(0, '<u>' + entrytext + '</u>', pageNum, str(id(page)))
```

It works ok, the problem is that page numbers turn out blue as well. I tried to look around SO and the user guide for ways to put a different style for each - but was unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Thanks.